# How to open a downloaded .ics file in Calendar app?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a webview, with an option for adding to calendar. I am able to download the ics file I'm getting in response and can see that file in local path. However in my app, I don't see any option to add that file in the device calendar. How can I achieve a way that the downloaded ics file gets opened in the calendar app and the event is added?

I do not want to do it using application.canOpenURL(url). The requirement is to download and then open that file.

Comment: Check [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+ics+Calendar+app) for possible solutions.

Comment: Doesn't the web view automatically give the option to add the calendar event to the Calendar app? Why eliminate that functionality by intercepting the link and downloading the file?